# how to get web services data from url?

Tags: ios, json, swift3

In this web services i need to get the data and to display as mentioned in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Lj8.png) can anyone help me how to pass this type url i don't have any idea about passing this type of web services to get and the url is

```
 let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2"
    var detailsArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
    var titleName = [String]()
    var productName = [String]()
    var children = [String]()
    var childrenArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
    var productsArray :[[String:AnyObject]] = []
    var name = [String]()

    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.detailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                print(self.detailsArray)
                for item in self.detailsArray{
                    if let detailDict = item as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "name"){
                            self.titleName.append(name as! String)
                            print(self.productName)
                        }
                    self.childrenArray = (detailDict.value(forKey: "children") as? [[String : AnyObject]])!
                    print(self.childrenArray)
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    print(self.productName)
                    print(self.titleName)
                    print(self.name)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: did you got response from web service ?

Comment: i was able to get but is it possible to pass it to table view as i had shown in above image @KKRocks

Comment: only some data i was getting and later it is going to crash @KKRocks

Comment: can you tell me where crashed your app ?

Comment: here it is crashing https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OKOX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
self.detailsArray = (jsonObj.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
      print(self.detailsArray)
      for item in self.detailsArray{
        if let detailDict = item as? [String : AnyObject] {
          if let name = detailDict["name"]{
            self.titleName.append(name as! String)
            print(self.productName)
          }
          if let dictChildren = detailDict["children"]{
        if ((dictChildren as? [Any]) != nil){
          self.childrenArray = dictChildren as! [[String : AnyObject]];
        }
        print(self.childrenArray)

      }
  }
```

Comment: i got object successful .

Comment: @vamsi try my answer.

Comment: In children array it is showing null in nslog @KKRocks

Comment: yes because in response children array not coming so

Comment: then how to get data inside children array @KKRocks

Comment: using detailDict["children"]["products"].

Comment: and in children array also there is products i need to get those elements  also how to get it help me bro as i am a trainee i was trying from a lot more days @KKRocks

Comment: using detailDict["children"] for children array and using detailDict["children"]["products"] this for product inside the children array.

Comment: after reading all the data from this then how to pass it to table view as mentioned in image ? @KKRocks

Comment: it is not easy because there are multiple section.

Comment: how to do then any idea ? @KKRocks

Comment: for some of the children array there will be no products then how to give the correct array order @KKRocks

Comment: yes but you need to make some customization . any library not suitable as your requirement.

Comment: there is any another way to implement as shown in image without using third party library ?@KKRocks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and following solution is working.

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            self.detailsArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
            print(self.detailsArray)
            for item in self.detailsArray{
                if let detailDict = item as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let name = detailDict["name"]{
                        self.titleName.append(name as! String)
                        print(self.productName)
                    }
                    self.childrenArray = (detailDict["children"]as? [[String : AnyObject]])!
                    print(self.childrenArray)
                }
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                print(self.productName)
                print(self.titleName)
                print(self.name)
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```